# Issue porting C code from 32 to 64 bit: fread causing access violation

Tags: c, malloc, 64-bit, fread

I am porting my C code from 32 to 64 bit in visual studio and having issues with an `fread` call which throws an exception `Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFFFF873B2830`.  The address it is writing to matches the pointer address returned by `malloc`.

I cannot see what would be causing this.  Any suggestions?

```
velo_error_t velo_read_binary_file(char input_file[], uint8_t **p_buffer, uint32_t *p_length) {
    // Returns error code, zero if normal:
    velo_error_t err_code = VELO_ERROR_NONE;
    // read input file.
    FILE *f = fopen(input_file, "rb");
    if (!f) {
        printf("File not valid.  File trying to open for reading:\n%s\n", input_file);
        err_code = VELO_ERROR_INVALID_FILE;
    } else {
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
        *p_length = ftell(f);
        fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
        *p_buffer = malloc(*p_length);
        if (*p_buffer) {
            fread(*p_buffer, 1, *p_length, f);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }
    return err_code;
}
```

Comment: Q: What's the value of *p_length in your debugger?  Q: Would you consider substituting a temp variable like "long length" inside your function?

Comment: Value of *p_length is 2998.  yes I'd consider anything!

Comment: Shouldn't `fread()` take a `size_t` for its 3rd parameter?  Which line are you hitting that fault on?

Comment: jwdonahue is correct. SUGGESTION: 1)  `size_t length = ftell(f);` 2) `*p_buffer = malloc(length);`, 3) `fread(*p_buffer, 1, length, f);` and finally 4) `*p_length = length;`.  Please let us know if it works.

Comment: Thank you.  Sounded promising, but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Please post an [mcve].

Comment: I have tried this, but in isolation it all works fine (same file) so something to do with context.  I think issue is likely to be the odd (very high) address returned by malloc.  Is there anything I could look for here?   I'll keep looking and report back if I resolve.  thank you

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. The problem might be in the calling code, or even totally elsewhere. You need to investigate this with your debugger,

Comment: After all: what about `uint32_t * p_length` -> `size_t *p_length`, and change the type also in the calling code.

Comment: I found it.  I as missing ```#include <stdlib.h>```.  This has burnt me before - visual studio in 32 bit mode seems to deal with missing header files so if you forget one it runs fine, but in 64 bit mode it doesnt.  Irritatingly it doesn't flag an error that malloc is undefined, and instead just returns nonsense.  thanks again for your help.

Comment: @bgarrood you should compile with all warninge enabled and consider them as errors. Especially "Implicit delcaration" warnings are actually errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a missing include (stdlib.h).  Visual Studio in 32 bit mode seems to deal with missing includes silently, and somehow finds the right library to use.  In 64 bit mode this doesn't work, but it doesn't give an error about a missing reference.  It just returns a (seemingly) random pointer address.

As @Jabberwocky states, its important to take notice of warnings in visual studio!

Comment: Also suggest increasing warning levels: the switch should be `/W4` or something similar.